# CSS: height overriding min-height: min-content

Tags: html, css, height

I have a div, that should open up to show full content on hover, but the `min-height` is not taking effect.

Here is a JSFiddle test:

https://jsfiddle.net/rb9pqked/

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .test {
      min-height: min-content;
      height: 50px;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="test">test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test</div>
</body>

</html>
```

If `min-height` is set to `80px` instead of `min-content´, it takes effect and div is enlarged.

All the text should be visible with `min-height: min-content`, but it is not. `height` is overriding the `min-height`, if it is set to `min-content`. 
Same is for `-webkit-min-content`.

This worked on Chrome and iOS before. I have iOS and Chrome 76, and it does not work on both.

Comment: works on chrome 75, but after updating to 76, it doesn't work anymore

Comment: Having the same problem and the accepted answer doesn't solve it. Is this a bug in Chorme?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the idea is to show just 50px when not hovering, and show all content when hovering, why not set the `max-height` when in normal state and then on `:hover` turn this max to `unset`?

```css
.test {
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.test:hover {
  max-height: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">test<br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
</div>
```

Comment: Smooth. I added the min-height: 50px; to avoid shrinking if content was smaller, but this solves my problem.